# Kernel Shutdown While model.predict() Keras Model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

so I'm currently having an issue that every time I predict my loaded model, my Jupyter Notebook's kernel shut down.

So I was given this Keras model that has this model summary:

```
    Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 100)               200       
_________________________________________________________________
re_lu_1 (ReLU)               (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 50)                5050      
_________________________________________________________________
re_lu_2 (ReLU)               (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 50)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 51        
=================================================================
Total params: 5,301
Trainable params: 5,301
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I was planning to save this model using [this method](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load) that I got online. I saved the entire model. Then, I tried to load the saved model onto a different notebook. Done dimension/shape adjustment and I started noticing that every time I did model.predict(), my kernel shuts and gave no error massages. So I started to do this backwards, which is trying to predict on the original notebook, where the model was trained. And I found no error. My hypothesis is:

1. There's nothing wrong with the model. Because this it can predict one data. Anything greater than that, it'll crush.
2. The problem came from saving and loading the model

This is my code for saving and loading my model

**MODEL ORIGIN NOTEBOOK**

Has anyone ever encountered the same problem? The below code is my code:

```
#Model architecture
#Model ANN
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(ReLU())
model.add(Dropout(.5))
model.add(Dense(50))
model.add(ReLU())
model.add(Dropout(.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=100, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))

# ATTEMPT 1 save the model to disk
filename = 'model_pake_pickle_bener.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

**DIFFERENT NOTEBOOK**

This is where things gone wrong

```
#Load the saved model
filename = 'model_pake_pickle_bener.sav'
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))

#reduce number of data used
bersih = bessp[:2]

#Introducing our dataset to tf (Voltage only)
X = bersih['Voltage_y'].values
y = bersih['SOC'].values

#Reshaping
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1)
y = y.reshape(y.shape[0], 1)

#Adjustment
X = np.asarray(X).astype('float32')

y = loaded_model.predict(X)
```

I've tried using h5 file and it ended up the same as the others.

Comment: is there some crash logs available?

Comment: My guess is that there's something missing when saving the model with `pickle`. When TF saves models to disk it also includes graph definitions (see the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize?hl=en#introduction) for more on this)

Comment: No, there is no crash logs given. However, when I used my notebook on Google Colab, it gave error messages "ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type float)." But this was before the reshaping part.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving and loading the model with the direct object methods? I noticed that you use `pickle`, but [it's recommended to use](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize?hl=en#how_to_save_and_load_a_model) (taken from the documentation):

```
model = ...  # Get model (Sequential, Functional Model, or Model subclass)
model.save('path/to/location')
```

To load the model in your second notebook:

```
from tensorflow import keras
model = keras.models.load_model('path/to/location')
```

Comment: Hey, yes, I have tried that way. Both h5 format and the normal one. Either way, Pickle and direct object method, wont work if I use them outside its original notebook, where the model was trained.

Comment: Are you using Colab? What I have noticed it that sometimes files won't be correctly synced to your mounted Google Drive.

Comment: No, I'm using Jupyter.